# unable to figure out who is consuming root disk space

Tags: disk-usage, lsblk

Team,
my system running `ubuntu 16 and k8s 1.13.5` is reporting 79% full and i tried several utilities and no avail what is actually consuming it. I tried several options but output of none is summing to `345G` or `83%`

below is using ncdu utility which does not correspond to df -h output

```
/dev/sda2       439G  345G   72G  83% /
```

Please ignore RAID below because it is mounted to different device and does not consume what / is reporting above.

```
ncdu 1.12 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
--- / --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3.4 TiB [##########] /raid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   33.2 GiB [          ] /var
    2.9 GiB [          ] /usr
  589.9 MiB [          ] /lib
  146.3 MiB [          ] /boot
  102.9 MiB [          ] /opt
   15.3 MiB [          ] /sbin
```

then I ran du
`du -s /*`

```
3090316 /usr
28696688    /var
```

then
`du -Pshx /* * 2>/dev/null`

```
14M /bin
141M    /boot
0   /dev
8.5M    /etc
4.1M    /home
4.0K    /host
0   /initrd.img
0   /initrd.img.old
590M    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
103M    /opt
0   /proc
3.4T    /raid
256K    /root
4.0M    /run
16M /sbin
8.0K    /snap
4.0K    /srv
0   /sys
11M /tmp
3.0G    /usr
29G /var
0   /vmlinuz
0   /vmlinuz.old
```

Comment: Long running server with many processes and deleted, but open files? See: https://serverfault.com/questions/310761/df-reports-wrong-free-space-for-an-ext4-partition

Comment: Which filesystem and which distro?

Comment: I assume /raid is another filesystem.  Unmount it and make sure that directory is actually empty.

Comment: Please ignore RAID below because it is mounted to different device and does not consume what / is reporting above.

Comment: `ubuntu 16 and k8s 1.13.5`